# How to prove: $a+b+c\le a^2+b^2+c^2$, if $abc=1$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $abc=1$. What is the simple(st) way to prove inequality 
$$
a+b+c \le a^2+b^2+c^2.
$$

(Of course, it can be generalized to $n$ variables).

Comment: How about Lagrange multipliers ? I take it to be "simple" since it requires little thought/tricks

Comment: @Belgi: Universal way :). I'd like to view something like AM-GM or Jensen's inequality. I hope it is easy to prove, but have problem with proof for now.

Comment: I would have thought there was a simpler way? For example, $$abc = 1 \Longrightarrow |a| > 1, |b| > 0, |c| > 0$$. WLOG it's clear. @Oleg567

Comment: Quite related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581992/let-a-b-c-be-positive-real-numbers-such-that-abc-1-prove-that-a2-b?rq=1

Comment: @Sawarnik, thank you for the related link. Nice answer of math110.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A).**
If values $~a,b,c~$ are positive, then
denote $m = \dfrac{a+b+c}{3},~$  ($m\ge \sqrt[3]{abc}=1$, AM-GM);    
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a=m+\alpha,\\ 
b=m+\beta, ~~~~~~(\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0).\\ 
c=m+\gamma.
\end{array}\right.~~~
$
Then 
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2 ~=~ 3m^2 + \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 ~\ge~ 3m ~=~ a+b+c.
$$

**B).** If some (two) of values $~a,b,c~$ are negative, then
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ~|a|+|b|+|c| ~>~ a+b+c.
$$

Comment: This way uses *only* AM-GM inequality. So, I think it is most elementary way.

Answer (score 7):

Assume $a,b,c>0$.

$$\text{Cauchy Schwarz:}\;\;3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq \left(a+b+c\right)^2\qquad\text{AM-GM}:a+b+c\geq 3$$
Done!

Answer (score 3):

We may assume that $a+b+c > 0$.

Then you can do this by using Cauchy-Schwarz and the power mean inequality as follows:

$$a+b+c \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \sqrt{3} \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way, we note that it is sufficient to prove for positive variables.  Now let $f(x) = x^2 - x - \log x$.  Then the  inequality is equivalent to $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \ge 0$

It is easy to see $f$ has a minimum at $x = 1$ when $f(1) = 0$, so $f(x) \ge 0$.

By this approach it is quite easy to extend to $\sum f(a_i) \ge 0$, given $\prod a_i = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

By replacing $a, b, c$ by $|a|, |b|, |c|$ if needed, we may assume they are non-negative. Then just apply Jensen inequality (or AM-GM inequality) to deduce that

$$ a+b+c = \sum_{\text{cyclic}} a^{4/3}b^{1/3}c^{1/3} \leq \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{4}{6}a^{2} + \frac{1}{6}b^{2} + \frac{1}{6}c^{2} = a^2 + b^2 + c^2. $$