# Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$. Prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge a + b + c$.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$. Prove that
>   $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge a + b + c$.

I'm supposed to prove this use AM-GM, but can't figure it out. Any hints?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

since
$$a^2+1\ge 2a$$
so
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+3\ge a+b+c+(a+b+c)\ge a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}=a+b+c+3$$
so
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge a+b+c$$

Comment: Nice answer. You seem to love inequalities, too:)

Comment: Hats off to u for the elegance

Answer (score 4):

Solution from  page 5 in [Thomas Mildorf's notes:](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Olympiad%20Inequalities%20-%20Thomas%20Mildorf%20(2006).pdf) first we homogenize the inequality with multipliying $(abc)^\frac{1}{3}$ and we get the following inequality
$$a^\frac{4}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}+a^\frac{1}{3}b^\frac{4}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}+a^\frac{1}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{4}{3}\:\leqslant\:
a^2+b^2+c^2\,,$$
then we can apply $GM\leqslant AM\,$ to obtain
$$a^\frac43b^\frac13 c^\frac13 \:\leqslant\: \frac{a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2}6\,.$$
And we can get in the same manner the other terms, and after adding them we are done.

Comment: Please add a link to the notes you mention to the answer, it'll help people who want more details and send more traffic towards the source of your solution.

Comment: Great I was keener to find this splitting from few mins and i shant underestimate mildorf's notes 

Answer (score 3):

By QM-AM for the first inequality and AM-GM for the second,

$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\geq\left( \frac{a+b+c}{3} \right)^2\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}\left( \sqrt[3]{abc} \right)$$

so since $abc=1, a^2+b^2+c^2\geq a+b+c$

Answer (score 2):

Using C-S and then AM-GM gives something shorter:
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge (a+b+c)\frac{(a+b+c)}{3} $$
$$\ge (a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{abc}=a+b+c$$
And we're done.