# if $abc=1$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

This is supposed to be an application of AM-GM inequality.

> if $abc=1$, then the following holds true: $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge a+b+c$

First of all,

$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3$

by a direct application of AM-GM.Also,we have

$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$

Next,we consider the expression

$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc\le a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2+1$

but that hardly helps.I know that

$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge (a+b+c)^2$

From the first derived inequality,we know that the left hand side of the above inequality is greater than or equal to 9.But I can't see how that can be used here.I know that we can get $a+b+c\ge 3$ using AM-GM but that does not take me a step closer to finding the solution(from what I can understand).Also,

$a^3+b^3+c^3\ge a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$

$(a+b+c)[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2]\ge a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$
A hint will be appreciated at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$. Prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge a + b + c$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581992/let-a-b-c-be-positive-real-numbers-such-that-abc-1-prove-that-a2-b)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice that for all real $a,b,c$,

$$(a - 1)^2 + (b-1)^2 + (c - 1)^2 \ge 0.$$
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2a - 2b - 2c + 3 \ge 0.$$
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge -3 + (a + b + c) + (a + b + c).$$

But by AM-GM, $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc} = 3$. So,
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge -3 + 3 + (a + b + c).$$
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge  a + b + c.$$

Equality is attained when $a = b = c = 1$.

(I really wish to put everything after the first line as a spoiler so that this answer becomes a hint, but I don't know how D:)

Comment: A spoiler is generated by starting your line with `>! `

Comment: Nice answer.May I know the motivation behind considering $(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2$?

Comment: I thought about how one can use $(a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (c - a)^2$ to prove $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$, and played around to get that :)

Comment: The AM-GM inequality is only generally applicable for non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @user236182 In the question it is mentioned that AM-GM is allowed for $a + b + c$.

Answer (score 7):

Use the fact that 
$$a^2+a^2+a^2+b+c \geq5\sqrt[5]{a^2.a^2.a^2.b.c}=5\sqrt[5]{a^6bc}=5a$$ since $abc=1$

Similarly, we get two more results, and adding them we get:
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(a+b+c) \geq 5(a+b+c) $$ which gives us our result.
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq a+b+c$$
$$Q.E.D.$$

Answer (score 6):

Here is an exotic solution based on geometry.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ be surfaces defined by

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M} : abc = 1
\quad \text{and} \quad
\mathcal{S} : a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} = a + b + c.
\end{align*}

Then we have the following observations:

1. $\mathcal{M}$ lies outside the sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$. Indeed, if $X = (a, b, c) \in \mathcal{M}$, then the *square-distance* from the origin $O$ satisfies
   $$ \overline{OX}^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}} = 3. $$
2. $\mathcal{S}$ is contained in the sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$. Indeed, $\mathcal{S}$ is the sphere of radius $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ centered at the point $P =  (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$, hence if $X = (a, b, c) \in \mathcal{S}$ then by the triangle inequality

$$ \overline{OX} \leq \overline{OP} + \overline{PX} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{3}.$$

Combining two facts, we find that $\mathcal{M}$ lies outside of $\mathcal{S}$ (possible except for the tangent point). Therefore

\begin{align*}
abc = 1
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (a, b, c) \in \mathcal{M} \\
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (a, b, c) \text{ lies outside } \mathcal{S} \\
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left(a - \tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \left(b - \tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \left(c - \tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2} \geq \tfrac{3}{4} \\
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \geq a + b + c.
\end{align*}

Comment: M lives outside the sphere of which center?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, $a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 6 \sqrt[6]{a^8b^2c^2} = 6 \sqrt[6]{a^6} = 6|a| \geq 6a$ by AM-GM. Adding the analogous inequalities $a^2+4b^2+c^2 \geq 6b$ and $a^2+b^2+4c^2 \geq 6c$ gives the result.

Comment: But what if $a<0$?

Comment: Notice that $a^2$, $b^2$ and $c^2$ are non-negative, thus applying AM-GM is allowed. We have $\sqrt[6]{a^6} = |a| \geq a$.

Comment: With that addition, the proof is correct (and actually quite nice). Note that I had already upvoted you before I thought about the negative number problem, and forgot to unupvote when I noticed it, so don't be surprised that I don't upvote after this comment.

Comment: Nice.But may I know the motivation behind considering $4a^2+b^2+c^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $(2,0,0)\succ\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)$, our inequality it's just Muirhead.

Comment: Love how all polynomial ineqs are muirhead-able or schur-able :v

Answer (score 1):

$GM\le AM\le RMS\implies GM\times AM\le RMS^2\implies a+b+c\le a^2+b^2+c^2$.