# When $abc=1$ find the minimum of $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Tags: inequality

When $abc=1$ find the minimum of $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

**My attempt**:I put $\frac{1}{bc}$ for $a$ and then I used AM-GM inequality.

$(\frac{1}{bc})^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3$

But finally we should get the answer $a+b+c$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I think this will help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740518/if-abc-1-then-a2b2c2-ge-abc

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that the minimum of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is $a+b+c$; the minimum (or infimum) must be independent of $a,b,c$. The answer given with the problem is nonsensical. But maybe the problem asked you to show that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge a+b+c$, and you misinterpreted the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM-GM says:

$$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3\ge\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$$

Comment: I told the answer should be $a+b+c$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari, Why it has to be?  Here the equality occurs if $a^2=b^2=c^2\implies (a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ or $(1,-1,-1)$

Comment: The answer is in our book.

Comment: @TahaAkbari if $a+b+c$ is the answer, then there is no minimum as you can arbitrarily minimize that expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily solve it using the method of lagrange multplier.
And answer would be 3

Comment: I thought it is 3 too. but the answer should be $a+b+c$