# If $abc=1$, does $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \geq a+b+c$?

Tags: inequality

This question comes in mind while solving another question.

> If $abc=1$, does $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \geq a+b+c$ ?

I wonder if this question ([if $abc=1$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge a+b+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740518/if-abc-1-then-a2b2c2-ge-abc)) helps?

I wondered if AM-GM could help, but the extra *square* keeps bothering me while solving it.

Another thought: If $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \geq 1$, then this statement will be true. But how can I prove it?

Comment: Quoting from the question you've linked: *First of all,* $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that question helps a lot! Note that by AM-GM inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3(a^2b^2c^2)^{1/3}=3$. Since $x^2\geq x$ for all $x\geq 1$, it follows that
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq a^2+b^2+c^2\geq a+b+c.$$

Comment: Really thank you! I did not realise that it was this simple.

Comment: Nice. In fact you’ve nearly shown LHS $\ge 3$RHS.

Comment: Well @Macavity LHS $\ge$ 3RHS is true

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use Lagrange multipliers method with $$f(a,b,c)=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2+a+b+c\\g(a,b,c)=abc=1\\\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose $a$, $b$, $c>0$ as that always seems to be assumed in these
sorts of problems. Then your inequality is equivalent to
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge abc(a+b+c)=a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab.$$

As $bc\le\frac12(b^2+c^2)$ etc. we get
$$a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab\le a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2$$
and that is clearly less than $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$.

We can do better:
$$\frac{a^4+b^4}2+2a^2b^2\ge3a^2b^2$$
etc. Therefore
$$a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab\le a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2
\le\frac13(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

By [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality) we have that

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge a^4+b^4+c^4\ge  a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab=abc(a+b+c)=a+b+c$$